# Upgrade Xibs for iPhone X

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, autoresize, iphone-x

I have a situation here and need to know your outlook:
suppose we have an app which uses "auto resize" mask instead of "auto layout". What will be the best approach to update all the screen for iPhone X? Do we have any tool which can do this for me?

Thanks in advance
Ankit